# URL host base directory parsing in bash

Tags: bash

I'm having some trouble parsing URLs in bash. They have the following format:

```
http(s)://some.host.com/some/web/directory/file
```

I want to extract only the protocol and the host string so that the end result is:

```
http(s)://some.host.com/
```

How can this be accomplished in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use grep:

```
grep -o 'https\?://[^/]\+/'
grep -Eo 'https?://[^/]+/'
```

Input can be from a pipe or a file.

And if your protocol part is literally `http(s)`, you can have:

```
grep -o 'http(s)://[^/]\+/'
```

Comment: the second one did it

Answer (score 0):

You could try this GNU sed command aslo,

```
$ echo 'http(s)://some.host.com/some/web/directory/file' | sed -r 's~^([^\/]*\/\/[^\/]*/).*~\1~g'
http(s)://some.host.com/
```